# Exchange 2016 CU23 giving error "upgrade the discovery mailboxes to R5 version"

Tags: exchange, windows-update, update, exchange-2016, microsoft

We have a hybrid 2016 Exchange setup that needs cumulative update 23. I have been stuck on this same error for some time now. In my research I have found that the issue has to do with needing the HomeMDB attribute to updated.

1. Go to the properties of a 2010 user account and locate the value that is set in the homeMDB attribute. Make a copy of the contents that are set in that attribute
2. Locate the CN=DiscoveryMailbox Search and go to properties
   The problem is none of our users have this attribute used so I am not sure where to locate this attribute.
   Below is the actual error:
   Error:
   The following error was generated when "$error.Clear();
   if (($RoleIsDatacenter -ne $true) -and ($RoleIsDatacenterDedicated -ne $true))
   {
   if (test-ExchangeServersWriteAccess -DomainController $RoleDomainController -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
   {

## upgrade the discovery mailboxes to R5 version, this will fix the RecipientDisplayType property of the discovery mailbox which was wrong in R4.

get-mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails DiscoveryMailbox -DomainController $RoleDomainController | where {$_.IsValid -eq $false} | set-mailbox -DomainController $RoleDomainController
$name = [Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.EnableMailbox]::DiscoveryMailboxUniqueName;
$dispname = [Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.EnableMailbox]::DiscoveryMailboxDisplayName;
$mbxs = @( get-mailbox -Filter {name -eq $name} -IgnoreDefaultScope -resultSize 1 );
if ( $mbxs.length -eq 0)
{
$dbs = @(get-MailboxDatabase -Server:$RoleFqdnOrName -DomainController $RoleDomainController);
if($dbs.Length -ne 0)
{
$mbxUser = @(get-user -Filter {name -eq $name} -IgnoreDefaultScope -ResultSize 1);
if ($mbxUser.Length -ne 0)
{
enable-mailbox -Discovery -identity $mbxUser[0] -DisplayName $dispname -database $dbs[0].Identity;
}
}
}
}
else
{
write-exchangesetuplog -info "Skipping creating Discovery Search Mailbox because of insufficient permission."
}
}
" was run: "Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Tasks.RecipientTaskException: The user's Active Directory account must be logon-disabled for linked, shared, or resource mailbox.
at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.ThrowError(Exception exception, ErrorCategory errorCategory, Object target, String helpUrl)
at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.EnableMailbox.PrepareRecipientObject(ADUser& user)
at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.EnableRecipientObjectTask`2.PrepareDataObject() at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.SetTaskBase`1.InternalValidate()
at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientObjectActionTask`2.InternalValidate()
at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.EnableMailbox.InternalValidate()
at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.b__91_1()
at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.InvokeRetryableFunc(String funcName, Action func, Boolean terminatePipelineIfFailed)".

Comment: Hi, have you upgraded exchange successfully? I'd appreciate it if you choose the most helpful post above and mark it as the best answer, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could follow below steps to find the homeMDB of the discoverysearch mailbox.

Start –> Run –> ADSIEDIT.MSC (should already know this since you used it to remove the MBX)

Default Naming Context –> “DC=Domain, DC=Local” –> CN=Users –> CN=DiscoverySearchMailbox {}
Right Click –> Properties  Find HomeMDB

Refer to a similar thread for your reference.
[Exchange 2016 CU19 - update problem : exchangeserver (reddit.com)](https://www.reddit.com/r/exchangeserver/comments/lzdclc/exchange_2016_cu19_update_problem/gqg79mk/)

*You can try checking of the arbitration mailboxes in ADUC manually and making sure they all have a value for the homeMDB.
They names will start with:
SystemMailbox{ , FederatedEmail., Migration.*

I also found the issue may occurred by the service was moving to disable state during the Installation.

Solution
During restoring services phase,  some of MS related services were changed to disabled state. I was keep starting all MS Exchange related services to complete the Installation,

Comment: Thanks! I will try this today and let you know.

Comment: Ok, please let me know until you finish the update. Good luck :)

Comment: How's every thing going now? If the issue has been solved, please do not forget to mark the helpful reply as the best answer. THANKS!

Comment: Hi， have you resolved this issue now?

Comment: No, still having the issue. I have filled in the HomeMDB attribute with the DB info and checked the services. Neither worked. I am considering deleting the mailboxes and recreating them next. We are a hybrid joined domain so hoping this wont cause any issues with anything that syncs to O365.

Comment: Also after further looking, the system mailboxes are located on DB01 which is corrupt and I cannot get to remount or repair correctly. Everything else is on DB02 which is fine and working. We technically dont need anything on DB01 but this may be why the error is happening. Hoping recreating them will help.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, after you delete the database. There may be some data stored in the AD. You may need delete clearly in ADSI EDIT.

Comment: How's everything going now?

Comment: Added answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to update Exchange. In order to complete this I had to do a couple things.

I replace the HomeMDB attribute with the info for DB02. The mailboxes did have this filled but it was for DB01 which is no longer being used and could not mount. I didn't realize this as the server is only used for creating users and distribution groups and syncing them to O365. This DB basically has nothing on it. I also was told by a colleague that the system and discovery mailboxes needed to be disabled to complete the update. This explains the part of the error that says "The user's Active Directory account must be logon-disabled for linked, shared, or resource mailbox" I understood this as the user running the update or a service account being used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to hear that issue has been solved. And thanks for your sharing about it : )
Issue: Upgrade Exchange failed with error "upgrade the discovery mailboxes to R5 version, this will fix the RecipientDisplayType property of the discovery mailbox which was wrong in R4."

Solution:
According to the error"The user's Active Directory account must be logon-disabled for linked, shared, or resource mailbox".
Exchange server can upgrade successfully after disabled the system and discovery mailboxes.
If the issue has been resolved, please mark the helpful replies as answers, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you should turn out to be missing HomeMDB for the DiscoverySearchMailbox;

- Open AD Users and Computers
- Click VIEW and tick "Advanced Features"
- Locate Exchange related mailboxes in the Users AD folder
- You will find DiscoverySearchMailbox, FederatedEmail, Migration and SystemMailbox (several)
- You should open all of them one by one, click on "Attribute Editor" tab and scroll down to "HomeMDB" and make a note of which ones are blank
- Open up that had the HomeMDB entry already filled in and copy the contents to clipboard
- Now Re-open the two that were blank and paste the HomeMDB found in the others
- Re-run Exchange setup, the mailbox service installation part finally will move on.

Hope it will fix your issue, also check if you are following all steps correctly for [installing Exchange Cumulative Updates](https://www.stellarinfo.com/article/install-exchange-cumulative-updates.php).